# How to display data in Jquery Week Calendar from Database

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, calendar, jquery-week-calendar

My application is in Asp.net MVC3 coded in c#.Net. I'm using Jquery Week Calendar for showing the time slot. I have successfully able to use and implement it. But now i want to show the values on the time slot from the database, which i'm not able to achieve.

**Following things i have tried:**

**1:** Create a function on `document.ready` and tried to filled the data to week Calendar data using viewbag.

suggest how can i achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

first collect your data from `DATABASE` ,convert it to `JSON` formate then pass it to 
  `weekcalender` jquery

EG:

here i take static data JSON

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

 events: [ 

{"id":"46_l","title":"CustomEvent-Chargement","start":"2013-12-02","end":"2013-12-03"},
{"id":"46_d","title":"Custom Event-Livraison","start":"2013-12-11","end":"2013-12-12"}

]

});
```